# Envio array, method POST

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Estimados compañeros, anteriormente enviaba mis ID por GET y me a causado problemas ya que un usuario podia cambiar los datos de otro usuario simplemente cambiando de ID.

Ahora he modificado mi codigo y estoy enviando mis ID por hidden method POST. El codigo es el siguiente:

```
<table class="table table-bordered text-center">
    <thead>
            <tr style="background:#2980b9;color:white;">
            <th  class="text-center">#</th>
            <th class="text-center">FECHA DE INSCRIPCIÓN</th>
            <th class="text-center">CURSO INSCRITO</th>
            <th class="text-center">CONDICION</th>
            <th class="text-center">NRO INSCRITOS</th>
            <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>        
    <?php $i=1; foreach ($data as $fila) { ?>   
    <form method="POST" action="<?= base_url()?>user_detalle/detalle">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>        
            <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fila->fec_cre)) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo fechaCastellano($fila->fec_ini) ?></td>             
            <?php
                if ($fila->est_ins == 0) {
                    echo '<td>Normal</td>';
                }elseif ($fila->est_ins == 1){
                    echo '<td>Anulado</td>';
                }else{
                    echo '<td>Reprogramado</td>';
                }
             ?>
            <td><?php echo $fila->num_ins ?></td>
            <td><?php if ($fila->est_ins == 1) { ?>
                <span class="text-danger">Anulado</span>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Detalle</button>
                <?php } ?>
            </td>           
        </tr>
            <input type="hidden" name="idinscripcion" value="<?php echo $fila->idinscripcion; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="idregistro" value="<?php echo $fila->idregistro; ?>">                      
    </tbody>
    </form>     
    <?php  } ?>
```

Este código me genera por cada linea un form y cumple con lo que quiero que es ocultar el ID para que no modifiquen los datos.

Mi pregunta es: Esta opción es valida?, hay una solución mejor? como hacen ustedes?

Cabe mencionar que trabajo con el framework Codeigniter.

Comment: ¿Porqué metes una tabla dentro de un formulario? Si necesitas un formulario, usa un formulario.

Comment: Estuvo mal planteado la solucion, acabo de crear un controller que valide los datos por get si corresponden al usuario. Ahora ya esta funcioando Bien.